# oracle duplicate rows based on a single column

Tags: sql, oracle11g, duplicates

How can I find out duplicate rows based on a single column. I have a table in oracle which has data as given below and it has duplicates. I'm trying to select and view all rows with duplicate employee ids as explained below

EMP table:

```
EmpId Fname Lname Mname Jobcode Status exp_date

1      Mike Jordan A    IT      W      12/2014
1      Mike Jordan A    IT      A      12/2014
2      Angela ruth C    sales   P      12/2015
2      Angela ruth C    IT      W      12/2015
3      Kelly  Mike B    sales   W      12/2015
```

From the above table i want to select all rows which duplicate empids such as below

```
EmpId Fname Lname Mname Jobcode Status exp_date

1      Mike Jordan A    IT      W      12/2014
1      Mike Jordan A    IT      A      12/2014
2      Angela ruth C    sales   P      12/2015
2      Angela ruth C    IT      W      12/2015
```

How can I do this? thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  EmpID
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY EmpID
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a478e/5)

Another way, *although I prefer above*, is to use `IN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
WHERE   EmpId IN
        (
            SELECT  EmpId
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY EmpId
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a478e/7)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now could you let me know how did u improve you sql skills. I want to be like you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option using a subquery and `COUNT OVER PARTITION BY` since you're using Oracle 11:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT EmpId, Fname, Lname, Mname, Jobcode, Status, exp_date,
    COUNT(EmpId) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId) EmpCount
  FROM    TableName 
  ) T
WHERE EmpCount > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d6e0/5) (Borrowed from JW)