# remove rows with some duplicate column value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

Suppose I have a table with column A like following :

```
a  
--
x  
y  
m  
x  
n  
y
```

I want to delete all rows that have duplicate a column value and keep just one value.
After this operation, my column would be like If you do :

```
select distinct a from A;
```

I [know how to select rows with repeated a column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291075/oracle-duplicate-rows-based-on-a-single-column) But I can't just replace select with DELETE because it would delete the unique values too.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which dbms ar u using , SQL Server or MySql ?

Comment: Oracle 9i :) Sorry I've just edited the tags ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, you can do this by using the hidden column `rowid` and a correlated subquery:

```
delete from a
    where rowid > (select min(rowid)
                   from a a2
                   where a.a = a2.a
                  );
```

Alternatively, you can phrase this as a `not in`:

```
delete from a
    where rowid not in (select min(rowid)
                        from a a2
                        group by a2.a
                       );
```

Comment: two rows in my table A with repeated column a values have not necessarily the same ROWID, only column a may be repeated, but other columns may have different values @Gordon Linoff

Comment: is there a way to delete in oracle using cte like mssql server ?

Comment: @mhasan . . . Oracle does not support CTEs with the `delete` statement, so there is no way to do that.

Comment: @mounaim . . . I don't understand your comment.  This is how you delete rows in a table in Oracle so you only keep one value.  In Oracle, two rows necessarily have different `ROWID`.

Comment: Could someone please explain clearly how ROWID works in Oracle ?

Comment: @mounaim . . . The place to start is with the documentation, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of CTE and [**Ranking function**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

```
;With cte As
(
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY colA ORDER BY colA) as rNum
From yourTable 
)

Delete From cte
Where rNum<>1
```

Comment: I think I understand your strategy here but what is the meaning of the 'PARTITION BY' 'WITH CTE AS' clauses @m hasan ?

Comment: Partition By Clause divides the column values into subsets acording to the column values and the ORDER BY clause the assigns rank to member of each subset.

Comment: Yes I understand now this (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) But I'm getting this error : ORA00923 "FROM keyword not found where expected" in my case (Oracle 9i) Have you already had this error @m hassan ?

Comment: Strangely , oracle doesnot seem to support deletion by using common table expression , unlike MS SQL Server... you should go by Gordon Linoff solution .. his solution fiddle is here ...http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d187/16

Comment: Ok Thank you m hassan for information :) I've already commented to Gordon Linoff why his solution wouldn't work for me because my rows with repeated column a values aren't having the same ROWID

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, You can use CTE and delete the duplicated rows. See the query below.

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT a,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY a)
   FROM A
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: Wow!  I didn't know you could CTEs with `delete` in Oracle.  Can you provide some documentation on this?  It returns an error in this simple SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9bb1/1.